# Convert HTML to PDF in Power Automate

Tags: html, json, onedrive, power-automate

I am working on Power Automate and trying to convert an HTML page into a pdf file. However, before the HTML page content loads completely, the conversion process takes place. As a result, the pdf file created is either blank or has a loading symbol.

I believe the need is to add a manual delay of a few seconds between page load and pdf file conversion, but am unable to do so.

Below is the concerned 'definition' file JSON code extracted after exported the Power Automate Flow. The connector for pdf conversion can be searched as "operationId":"ConvertFileByPath"

```html
{"name":"611652cf-aec0-4733-8871-b0f0f40af783","id":"/providers/Microsoft.Flow/flows/611652cf-aec0-4733-8871-b0f0f40af783","type":"Microsoft.Flow/flows","properties":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_logicflows","displayName":"Enterprise
Assessment Tool","definition":{"metadata":{"workflowEntityId":null,"creator":{"id":"4205125c-5d6f-4e96-b565-709e4a8dcbde","type":"User","tenantId":"971f0e31-00d6-4e42-b8e0-47b342bc4455"},"provisioningMethod":"FromDefinition","failureAlertSubscription":true,"clientLastModifiedTime":"2020-03-20T08:55:47.5792257Z"},"$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#","contentVersion":"1.0.0.0","parameters":{"$connections":{"defaultValue":{},"type":"Object"},"$authentication":{"defaultValue":{},"type":"SecureObject"}},"triggers":{"When_a_new_response_is_submitted":{"type":"OpenApiConnectionWebhook","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_microsoftforms","connectionName":"shared_microsoftforms_2","operationId":"CreateFormWebhook"},"parameters":{"form_id":"MQ4fl9YAQk644EezQrxEVVwSBUJvXZZOtWVwnkqNy95UNkVCVlJZSVlHQlBEWFhOMkFJUE5PT1pSWS4u"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}}},"actions":{"Apply_to_each":{"foreach":"@triggerOutputs()?['body/value']","actions":{"Get_response_details":{"runAfter":{},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_microsoftforms","connectionName":"shared_microsoftforms_2","operationId":"GetFormResponseById"},"parameters":{"form_id":"MQ4fl9YAQk644EezQrxEVVwSBUJvXZZOtWVwnkqNy95UNkVCVlJZSVlHQlBEWFhOMkFJUE5PT1pSWS4u","response_id":"@items('Apply_to_each')?['resourceData/responseId']"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}},"Add_a_row_into_a_table":{"runAfter":{"Get_response_details":["Succeeded"]},"metadata":{"016AIIWUWO74RBMREYLVAIQPOYYNXRWO3P":"/Enterprise
Assessment Tool.xlsx","tableId":"{9C186D95-CBB6-477E-8699-17B3089A0368}","01BSP3ENPNPETDO5YJUVBI2X6MEG5ARSKV":"/Enterprise Assessment Tool.xlsx"},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_excelonlinebusiness","connectionName":"shared_excelonlinebusiness_1","operationId":"AddRowV2"},"parameters":{"source":"me","drive":"b!wjpSLG6KfES6F9-MfcSm-aeq5llhoTVMpfXuBQBmrywjSt-PswuwSbm1_6BG5sFo","file":"01BSP3ENPNPETDO5YJUVBI2X6MEG5ARSKV","table":"{9C186D95-CBB6-477E-8699-17B3089A0368}","item/ID":"@items('Apply_to_each')?['resourceData/responseId']","item/Your
name":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r6b6a573a836044eab553ba2e0ab92446']","item/Organization’s Name":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/ra2af29025bff44bbac289f9c61c76666']","item/Your Email Address":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rf505d38dc6334aa7b69d2c77f230f09e']","item/Providing
clear and effective leadership":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r4b5eade301884d9b8629c9b38d9a3c2d']","item/Anticipating opportunities and threats to keep us ahead of change":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rca90ae117bc347f9886072f118ceb630']","item/Willingness
to take on risks for long-term growth, even if that could decrease current year profits":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rc8656608760f4e19abc1d78ecacbf825']","item/Making disciplined IT investment decisions":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r14226cb30f604f20a626157ec1786086']","item/Using
IT to gain competitive advantage":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r963c2865db4d4e90b20fa82547a48c62']","item/Articulating a clear and consistent vision to employees, consumers and partners":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r01698107f2ea4286a8f59ec20f17f3b8']","item/Enabling
the enterprise to navigate change":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r2c02b757c2444656a4c32388e2353724']","item/Fostering and changing the culture in IT":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r09d450406bfb477bb55cfd5dd572eb09']","item/Please
rate the clarity and consistency of your enterprise’s overall business strategy_x002e_":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r5bdc0ce9ba0b46348149fb2422b4e041']","item/Please indicate the nature of your organization’s CIO’s (or the most senior IT
leader’s) relationship with the CEO (or most senior Business executive)_x002e_":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r29c1767ce4bd4da6bec697ede635a908']","item/Has your organization faced any of these situations in the past four years? Please select
all that apply_x002e_":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rb4f8047c739d42938a52145e9a9cbef1']","item/Please share some details regarding the business disruption that you faced in the past four years_x002e_":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r7652d524e6524ba19fe6c629c4869aa0']","item/External
disruption of your business environment":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rd3d4bb9074a2411d9234551e0092500c']","item/Adverse regulatory intervention":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rc01f99fd45e74f5695e7fbcbcd66b6a4']","item/Cyber security
issue":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/reb816f5b028b43ccb22128f0bac6bc00']","item/IT Service failure":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r95c7899a06e74c04b6a4f96fb905abe8']","item/Product~1service failure":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r15ea7200480b45febe0384a5ad4fe683']","item/Operating
cost pressure":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r952f66721ebf48b6bb9e23f64273ae6a']","item/Labor disruption":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/ree57c3756cc04cf8b0d37e158256b1ef']","item/Shifting consumer demand":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r712b33b666694e80be27b2bcfb4bba86']","item/Funding
shortfall":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r493be3af3d244d638863da8b4e68fadc']","item/Organizational disruption":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r90bcccc8a1c3475186f5454677e9199a']","item/Some other disruptive business situation":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r939f57c83c054ab08d6c64c33bb5c62b']","item/The
overall business performance of the enterprise":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r729caa64609d4b998cfd200997bdca41']","item/Speed at which new business initiatives are launched":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r3061360c935d4f0093939e6b64bec6b7']","item/Ability
to fund new business initiatives":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rb186360b5d6a455d8ed624c1ab6a8ac0']","item/Speed at which business initiatives are successfully completed":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r3061360c935d4f0093939e6b64bec6b7']","item/Ability
to use data to achieve intended outcomes":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r2f1fc86f6d6f4cf6a78528bdf5b8e7e2']","item/Ability to attract the right talent to fill our needs":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rc3a23d40f20f49b78cab3880f0c8db38']","item/Ability
to get value from new business initiatives":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r4e4371bf1cdc472c8935bc398f7751b5']","item/IT budget growth":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rc0a78909625144acbc4d9d94658b0c74']","item/Operating cost competitiveness":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rac841e5b9e064ee88ec84dd54f48e40e']","item/Reputation
as an innovative enterprise":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r5ebbb6aebc8e4623bf987dca1e01afd1']","item/Our long-term viability":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rb83eaa31847f4306a54fa6375d5d544d']","item/The stability of the leadership
team (CEO and downward)":"@outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r7ac35c66284e4215b4dd6ac173134b54']"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}}},"runAfter":{},"type":"Foreach"},"Refresh_a_dataset":{"runAfter":{"Delay_2":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_powerbi","connectionName":"shared_powerbi","operationId":"RefreshDataset"},"parameters":{"groupid":"42cf205d-726b-418a-b227-d03cbcaa9f6b","datasetid":"36269b8f-45cd-43c7-a2fa-a3995da63c51"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}},"Delay":{"runAfter":{"Refresh_a_dataset":["Succeeded"]},"type":"Wait","inputs":{"interval":{"count":1,"unit":"Minute"}}},"Delay_2":{"runAfter":{"Apply_to_each":["Succeeded"]},"type":"Wait","inputs":{"interval":{"count":1,"unit":"Minute"}}},"Apply_to_each_3":{"foreach":"@triggerOutputs()?['body/value']","actions":{"Get_response_details_3":{"runAfter":{},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_microsoftforms","connectionName":"shared_microsoftforms_2","operationId":"GetFormResponseById"},"parameters":{"form_id":"MQ4fl9YAQk644EezQrxEVVwSBUJvXZZOtWVwnkqNy95UNkVCVlJZSVlHQlBEWFhOMkFJUE5PT1pSWS4u","response_id":"@items('Apply_to_each_3')?['resourceData/responseId']"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}},"Convert_HTML_to_PDF":{"runAfter":{"Get_response_details_3":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_encodiandocumentmanager","connectionName":"shared_encodiandocumentmanager","operationId":"HtmlToPDF"},"parameters":{"operation/outputFilename":"Enterprise
Fitness Assessment Report_@{outputs('Get_response_details_3')?['body/ra2af29025bff44bbac289f9c61c76666']}","operation/htmlData":"
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>\n\n

<head>\n
  <script>
    \
    n\ nwindow.addEventListener('load', function() {\
          nsetInterval(function() {\
                ndocument.getElementById(\"delayedText\").style.visibility = \"visible\";\n},10000);\n\n}, false);\n\n/*window.onload = function(){\n \n var theDelay = 60;\n  var timer = setTimeout(\"showText()\",theDelay*1000)\n}\nfunction showText(){\n  document.getElementById(\"delayedText\").style.visibility = \"visible\";\n}*/\n\n\n
  </script>\n</head>\n\n

<body>\n
  <div id=\ "delayedText\" style=\ "visibility:hidden\">This is a test\n\n<iframe width=\ "1140\" height=\ "541.25\" src=\
      "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=d27f0160-eb09-442b-a7ab-ded938ed33ec&autoAuth=true&ctid=971f0e31-00d6-4e42-b8e0-47b342bc4455&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtdXMtcmVkaXJlY3QuYW5hbHlzaXMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvIn0%3D\" frameborder=\ "0\" allowFullScreen=\ "true\"></iframe>\n</div>\n\n</body>\n

</html>","operation/pageOrientation":"Landscape","operation/pageSize":"A4","operation/viewPort":"Default","operation/MarginTop":25,"operation/MarginBottom":25,"operation/MarginRight":25,"operation/MarginLeft":25,"operation/enableBookmarks":true,"operation/enableJavaScript":true,"operation/enableHyperlinks":true,"operation/createPdfForm":false,"operation/decodeHtmlData":true,"operation/cssType":"Screen","operation/repeatTableHeader":true,"operation/repeatTableFooter":true,"operation/splitImages":false,"operation/splitTextLines":false,"operation/encoding":"UTF8","operation/FinalOperation":true},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}},"Create_file":{"runAfter":{"Convert_HTML_to_PDF":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_onedriveforbusiness","connectionName":"shared_onedriveforbusiness","operationId":"CreateFile"},"parameters":{"folderPath":"/Enterprise
Assessment Reports","name":"@outputs('Convert_HTML_to_PDF')?['body/Filename']","body":"@outputs('Convert_HTML_to_PDF')?['body/FileContent']"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"},"runtimeConfiguration":{"contentTransfer":{"transferMode":"Chunked"}}},"Send_an_email":{"runAfter":{"Create_file":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365","connectionName":"shared_office365","operationId":"SendEmailV2"},"parameters":{"emailMessage/To":"@outputs('Get_response_details_3')?['body/rf505d38dc6334aa7b69d2c77f230f09e']","emailMessage/Subject":"Gartner
Enterprise Fitness Assessment Report","emailMessage/Body":"
<p>Hi @{outputs('Get_response_details_3')?['body/r6b6a573a836044eab553ba2e0ab92446']}<br>\n<br>\nThanks for submitting your response!&nbsp;Please view the attachement for your organisation's assessment.<br>\n<br>\nTeam PRM</p>","emailMessage/From":"Prakhar.Gupta@gartner.com","emailMessage/Attachments":[{"Name":"@outputs('Convert_HTML_to_PDF')?['body/Filename']","ContentBytes":"@outputs('Convert_HTML_to_PDF')?['body/FileContent']"}]},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}}},"runAfter":{"Send_an_email_(V2)":["Succeeded"]},"type":"Foreach"},"Send_an_email_(V2)":{"runAfter":{"Create_file_3":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365","connectionName":"shared_office365","operationId":"SendEmailV2"},"parameters":{"emailMessage/To":"Prakhar.Gupta@gartner.com","emailMessage/Subject":"test","emailMessage/Body":"
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>\n\n

<head>\n
  <script>
    \
    n\ nwindow.addEventListener('load', function() {\
          nsetInterval(function() {\
                ndocument.getElementById(\"delayedText\").style.visibility = \"visible\";\n},10000);\n\n}, false);\n\n/*window.onload = function(){\n \n var theDelay = 60;\n  var timer = setTimeout(\"showText()\",theDelay*1000)\n}\nfunction showText(){\n  document.getElementById(\"delayedText\").style.visibility = \"visible\";\n}*/\n\n\n
  </script>\n</head>\n\n

<body>\n
  <div id=\ "delayedText\" style=\ "visibility:hidden\">This is a test\n\n<iframe width=\ "1140\" height=\ "541.25\" src=\
      "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=d27f0160-eb09-442b-a7ab-ded938ed33ec&autoAuth=true&ctid=971f0e31-00d6-4e42-b8e0-47b342bc4455&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtdXMtcmVkaXJlY3QuYW5hbHlzaXMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvIn0%3D\" frameborder=\ "0\" allowFullScreen=\ "true\"></iframe>\n</div>\n\n</body>\n

</html>"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}},"Create_file_2":{"runAfter":{"Delay":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_onedriveforbusiness","connectionName":"shared_onedriveforbusiness","operationId":"CreateFile"},"parameters":{"folderPath":"/Enterprise
Assessment Reports","name":"Test.html","body":"
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>\n\n

<head>\n
  <script>
    \
    n\ nwindow.addEventListener('load', function() {\
          nsetInterval(function() {\
                ndocument.getElementById(\"delayedText\").style.visibility = \"visible\";\n},10000);\n\n}, false);\n\n/*window.onload = function(){\n \n var theDelay = 60;\n  var timer = setTimeout(\"showText()\",theDelay*1000)\n}\nfunction showText(){\n  document.getElementById(\"delayedText\").style.visibility = \"visible\";\n}*/\n\n\n
  </script>\n</head>\n\n

<body>\n
  <div id=\ "delayedText\" style=\ "visibility:hidden\">This is a test\n\n<iframe width=\ "1140\" height=\ "541.25\" src=\
      "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=d27f0160-eb09-442b-a7ab-ded938ed33ec&autoAuth=true&ctid=971f0e31-00d6-4e42-b8e0-47b342bc4455&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93YWJpLXdlc3QtdXMtcmVkaXJlY3QuYW5hbHlzaXMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvIn0%3D\" frameborder=\ "0\" allowFullScreen=\ "true\"></iframe>\n</div>\n\n</body>\n

</html>"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"},"runtimeConfiguration":{"contentTransfer":{"transferMode":"Chunked"}}},"Delay_3":{"runAfter":{"Create_file_2":["Succeeded"]},"type":"Wait","inputs":{"interval":{"count":3,"unit":"Minute"}}},"Convert_file_using_path":{"runAfter":{"Delay_3":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_onedriveforbusiness","connectionName":"shared_onedriveforbusiness","operationId":"ConvertFileByPath"},"parameters":{"path":"@outputs('Create_file_2')?['body/Path']","type":"PDF"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"}},"Create_file_3":{"runAfter":{"Convert_file_using_path":["Succeeded"]},"type":"OpenApiConnection","inputs":{"host":{"apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_onedriveforbusiness","connectionName":"shared_onedriveforbusiness","operationId":"CreateFile"},"parameters":{"folderPath":"/Enterprise
Assessment Reports","name":"@outputs('Convert_file_using_path')?['headers/x-ms-file-name']","body":"@outputs('Convert_file_using_path')?['body']"},"authentication":"@parameters('$authentication')"},"runtimeConfiguration":{"contentTransfer":{"transferMode":"Chunked"}}}},"outputs":{},"description":"Track
Microsoft Forms responses in an Excel Online (Business) spreadsheet. The spreadsheet must have columns: SubmissionTime, ResponderEmail."},"connectionReferences":{"shared_microsoftforms_2":{"connectionName":"shared-microsoftform-ff875ca3-62f2-4c71-bed9-8d02ce26ada2","source":"Embedded","id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_microsoftforms","tier":"NotSpecified"},"shared_excelonlinebusiness_1":{"connectionName":"shared-excelonlinebu-aabd11c2-e15f-4595-a539-d4ffe5ecd544","source":"Embedded","id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_excelonlinebusiness","tier":"NotSpecified"},"shared_powerbi":{"connectionName":"shared-powerbi-07a589e5-e541-4241-83c7-2e5ba184ec9f","source":"Embedded","id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_powerbi","tier":"NotSpecified"},"shared_encodiandocumentmanager":{"connectionName":"shared-encodiandocum-29f09c50-052b-4d59-8c60-7876ab0cf806","source":"Embedded","id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_encodiandocumentmanager","tier":"NotSpecified"},"shared_onedriveforbusiness":{"connectionName":"shared-onedriveforbu-2262692c-87ba-4be3-a32d-febd64f70219","source":"Embedded","id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_onedriveforbusiness","tier":"NotSpecified"},"shared_office365":{"connectionName":"shared-office365-28369e56-7ed4-431e-9b7b-ba4930b0f010","source":"Embedded","id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365","tier":"NotSpecified"}},"flowFailureAlertSubscribed":false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Run after property](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/error-handling/) on the action to get the HTML.

So once the action return then you convert your PDF

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jean!
HTML page load and PDF conversion are taking place are not taking place separately. They are in fact there in the same step of Power Automate - 'Convert file using path' (which is an Action there for 'One Drive for Business').
Thus, this workaround of 'Do until run after' wouldn't help here.